# Retrieving relationships of relationships using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need a invite list to show who invites are showing. But i think i need Relations that retrieving relations

**My relations:**

- CompanyModel
- InviteModel

So I look to the documentation of "Eager Loading" but i dont get how it works and how i need to use this..

```
 public function company() {

    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Manage\Company' );
}

public function invites() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Manage\Invite' )->orderBy('email')->orderBy('id');
}
```

Comment: Are these functions on a single model? Could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah this functions is on a single model: I will that when i click on the invites tab. That i see all the invites that have been send.

Comment: Whats the structure like? One company has many invites right (one to many)?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the company data with the relation of invites.

**Try** this:

```
$company = CompanyModel::with('invites')->get();
dd($company);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the relationship of one company may have multiple invites :

`Compony` Model :

```
public function invites() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Manage\Invite' )->orderBy('email')->orderBy('id');
}
```

`Invite` Model :

```
public function company() {

    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Manage\Company' );
}
```

Getting invites of a specific company :

```
$company = Company::find($companyId);
$invites = $company->invites;
```

Getting all companies and their respective invites :

```
$companies = Company::with('invites')->get();
```

Then you can loop through the company and get invites of each company :

```
foreach($companies as $company){
    $invites = $company->invites;
}
```